# librarian-puppet fails to install on windows

Tags: windows, puppet, librarian

I am new to puppet. I am trying to install librarian-puppet in my windows system. I have followed the following installation steps before I started to install `librarian-puppet` :

1. Download and install puppet from the windows msi file from https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/windows/ (NOT gem install puppet).
2. You must run everything from the "Start Command Prompt with Puppet" not a normal Windows Command prompt.
3. Before installing librarian-puppet the the Ruby DevKit is needed:

   a. Select "Start Command Prompt with Puppet" to go to a Command Windows.

   b. Download and install devkit from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

   c. In the devkit directory run “ruby dk.rb init”.

   d. Edit the config.yml generated and add the the path of the ruby install for puppet
       (it will be /sys/ruby).

   e. run “ruby dk.rb install” to bind it to the puppet ruby installation.

and finally I did:

```
gem install librarian-puppet
```

But the error I get is:

```
ERROR:  Error installing librarian-puppet:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

and the output of execution looks like this:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing librarian-puppet:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

Am I missing something here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be pertinent output above the error message. Can you share some more?

Comment: Ah. You lack the `make` tool.

Comment: Since this is installing from the gem, apparently, you may be hitting [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231713/vagrant-with-librarian-puppet-broken).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install librarian-puppet 1.1.x or later it should not require the json gem that fails to build